# In views, how do I show posts from this calendar day, ten years ago?

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I have a view in which I want to display posts that I made on this *date* 10 years ago. I can get close but not exactly what I want by setting the view's filter  to the following:

"Authored On is between: (offset) `-10 year` and `-10 year +1 day`"

My problem is that if it's currently 1pm on Dec. 17, 2019, I want to see all posts from the Dec. 17, 2009, regardless of hour posted. Instead I am seeing posts from Dec. 16, 2009 1pm to Dec. 17, 2009 1pm. I don't care what time the post was authored at, I just want it to show if the **calendar day** from 10 years ago is the same.

How can I set up my filter to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you did, create two filters for the date range and then use the following values

```
-10 years midnight 
-10 years +1 day midnight
```

Remember to select

```
An offset from the current time such as "+1 day" or "-2 hours -30 minutes"
```

If you want to do this programmatically you can create a date filter and set the actual date values from code for the filter range.

You can create the date filter and set the filter value programmatically like the following

[How do I programmatically render a view that has exposed filters?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274371/how-do-i-programmatically-render-a-view-that-has-exposed-filters)

Comment: Um, that question has no accepted answer. I don't want an exposed filter or a contextual filter. I am looking for a way to do this in the standard (for dummies like me) Views interface under _Filter Criteria_.

Comment: @Tantalus - I have updated the answer with something you can do without code. Can you please check if this works for you?

Comment: I think this is probably right. It's not exactly working in my Drupal install. Today is the 17th and I am still seeing items from the 16th. But, when I use your format in a tiny php file like this `<?php echo date('F j, Y g:i a', strtotime('-10 year midnight')); ?>` is outputs exactly the correct time. This leads me to think that maybe my Drupal install or local dev environment is not set up for my correct timezone.

Comment: Well, I checked my timezone settings and everything is set to CST. I have it working now with the following: `-10 year +1 day midnight` to `-10 year +1 day midnight +25 hours`. I tested by creating backdated posts at 12:01am 2009/12/17 and 11:59pm 2009/12/17. I have no idea why this worked and yours didn't. Maybe leap years? I can live with this, and I'll mark your answer as correct. It got me moving in the right direction at least.